# Get the real IP address when using a reverse tunnel with ssh

Tags: networking, ssh, tunnel

Let's say I open this tunnel from my local:

```
$ ssh -l user@135.95.66.88 -R 2401:135.115.12.68:2401
```

Then from 135.95.66.88 I can verify the tunnel:

$ telnet localhost 2401

I know that by using lsof I can see the IP address behind the ssh sessions (my local IP).

But, how can I know from (135.95.66.88) what IP address is the traffic being sent to (in this case 135.115.12.68).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Once the session is established (`telnet 2401`), You should see network connection via:

```
netstat -anp
```

Last column in this case show PID/command. Since You know ssh session, just grep `netstat` output for PID You are interested in.

This should work on Linux. On other *NIX'es netstat dosn't always has `-p` option.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but it refers to the localhost, this is the output:
tcp        0      0 ::1:31156                   ::1:2401                    ESTABLISHED 11807/telnet

Comment: Then filter out which PID is LISTEN'ing on 2401/tcp and then filter by this PId (You'll see where it connects). Similar data may be obtained by using `lsof -p PID`.